# Trying to do an NVL with a date format

Tags: java, xml, oracle, date

I've got some dates in a column `LASTMODIFIED` that have this date format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`. I'm trying to just get it to display like `MM/DD`. So I'm using this: `NVL(to_char(d.LASTMODIFIED, 'MM/DD'), '11/11') as LASTMODIFIED`

When I run the query in aqua data studio, the column displays the dates that I want, however in my xml, when I try to pull the date from my xml sql query using `<param name="lastmodified">`, I get dates that look like this `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.0`

Comment: Perhaps you could add your XML SQL query to the question?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the XML format to accept strings.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm not sure what I should look for to try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: ok , let's simplify it a bit , how do you generate the XML in the first place, try to post some code pls.

Answer (score 0):

I think variable which is holding this value from database is date format try to change it to string.